# Model selection in a paper: what to say about the dropped variables?

Tags: model-selection, reporting

I have a question (simpler than my previous post today I hope!), which is probably very stupid as nobody has never asked it before.

Lets say I am trying to explain the effect of 3 variables (A, B and C) on a dependent one (Y). Biologically speaking, A and B should really have an effect on Y. So I am testing:

*Y ~ A + B + C*

But when I use a model selection method (whatever the method is), the 'best' model, the one that fits the data the best, drops A. So I end up with:

*Y ~ B + C*

**What can I say about A then?**

Can I cite something to justify the dropping (the F statistics, something about the AIC/BIC, etc)?

**OR**

If I need to show that A has no effect, do I need to use the full model anyway?

Comment: AIC, BIC, DIC, Likelihood Ratio, cross-validation, etc... are tools that you can use depending on the features of the model you are interested on. If they indicate that A can be dropped, then you could use the [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) to defend the model $B+C$. The other post is interestig, but a bit long. Shorter questions seem to be more successful, you know, the popular [TL;DR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read).

Comment: Thanks. And I agree for the tl;dr thing, but I like to be clear, and thats also a very specific case, so I had to fully describe it. Thats the complexity of that dataset that makes it challenging to analyze.

Comment: And for your answer here: it's not really my question though=> I want to know what to say about the dropped variable. I need a way to prove that it had no effect.

Comment: Don't confuse dropping a variable with having no effect, Joe! For example, let y ~ a+d+e, b=a/2+2d+e/2, c=a/2-d+e/2, with d, e, (and the implicit error) all small compared to the variation in a.  Then a may have a profound effect on y, but (due to its association with b and c) is unnecessary in the model (and won't even be significant in the full model y ~ a+b+c); the best model would be y ~ b+c (because this equals a+d+e).

Comment: @whuber That's very well-put.  Why not make it an answer?

Comment: You wouldn't show A has *no* effect, unless the coefficient is exactly 0, which won't happen except in some very odd cases. You may show the estimated effect is small.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys! I can know go on with my stats and finally write that paper :)

Comment: Thanks @Matt, but my comment wasn't a real answer, although it may have shed some light on the subtleties involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your aim.  Since A "really should" have an effect on Y but appears not to, I would definitely include the full model.  As Procrastinator suggests, model selection might be useful to propose a parsimonious new model - if that's your objective.  But if your objective is to estimate the relationships between your predictors and Y, then I don't think you need a model selection step at all - just present your full model results.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess I got confused about the role of model selection, which is probably not appropriate in that case. I just thought that 'fitting the data better' was better, but actually it's not here!